# How to communicate with websocket server with Go as client

Tags: go, websocket

I know github.com/gorilla or golang.org/x/net can provide a websocket server. But I want Go as client (not html/js or python) communicate with server.

So I want to know how to communicate with websocket server with Go as client.

some **go code** like js:

```
socket = new WebSocket(...);
socket.onopen ...;
socket.onmessage ...;
```

Comment: You can use a [`Dialer`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Dialer), e.g. the [default one](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket#DefaultDialer), then call its [`Dial`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Dialer.Dial) method. Then you can use read methods like [`ReadJSON`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.ReadJSON) or write methods like WriteJSON. See the [examples](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples)

Comment: To add to xarantolus' comment, See the [Gorilla Client and Server Example](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/echo#client-and-server-example) for an example websocket client written in Go.  Search for [go websocket dialer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgo%5D+websocket+dialer) on this site to find many questions on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Address string as

```
var addr = flag.String("addr", "172.20.10.150:8080", "http service address")
```

This is how I connect to the websocket server:

```
flag.Parse()
log.SetFlags(0)

interrupt := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(interrupt, os.Interrupt)

u := url.URL{Scheme: "ws", Host: *addr, Path: "/ws"}
log.Printf("connecting to %s", u.String())

c, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(u.String(), nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("dial:", err)
}
defer c.Close()
```

I then use c variable to write or read:
_, p, err := c.ReadMessage()